# Bootstrap, clear both doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap front-end framework.

I want to get the following result:
two columns:

1. in the first two rows of four columns
2. Second one large column

The sample code below, but it does not work .. [see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQRN4/)

There is padding on the left side in the new row to the first column

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span7 tlo">
        <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
        <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
        <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
        <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
        <div style="clear: both;" class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
        <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
        <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
        <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span5 tlo2">
        <h1>AWESOME extra text!</h1>
        <h2>THIS i s really C00L</h2>
        <h3>My files, my problems ;)</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use nested `row-fluid`s to accomplish this: http://jsfiddle.net/QQRN4/7/

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span7 tlo">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
            <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
            <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
            <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
            <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
            <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
            <div class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span5 tlo2">
         <h1>AWESOME extra text!</h1>
         <h2>THIS i s really C00L</h2>
         <h3>My files, my problems ;)</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I linked back to your fiddle instead of my changes in the first post.

Comment: and how I can delete this spaccing between span7 and span4? (column 1 with 2 rows and column 2 with big 'box')? but row-fluid should be 100% width..

Comment: Looks like you were missing the correct Bootstrap. You need the responsive capabilities included - that's why it wasn't working! I updated the fiddle: I took out all the Bootstrap you had copy-pasted, and included it via the left-hand options. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

and

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;    
}
```

You can remove left margin from div with `clear`:

```
<div style="clear: both; margin-left: 0px;" class="span3 tlo2 my_height_box">aabc</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQRN4/1/)

Or replace left margin from all this divs with `margin-right`

Comment: right. i have tried margin-left:0px; in css but it won't work. when i type it in code it starts to working